# Vertical alignment of Images inside DIV

Tags: css

I am retrieving a bulk images through response and I need to arrange them inside a `div` tag and all the images are placing one below the other but I need to arrange them vertical (i.e. side by side)

So how do I do that?
And I followed this tutorial but I can arrange only text?

http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Can anyone suggest me the right way?

Here is my code:

```
$('#showfilelist').append("<div id=" + file.id + "><a href='uploads/" +
file.target_name + "' target='_blank' rel='gallery'><img src='thumbs/" +
file.target_name + "' border='0'/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>");
```

Here is what I'm getting the result

[image]

Plupload Css:

```
    /*
   Plupload
------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.plupload_button {cursor: pointer;}

.plupload_wrapper {
    font: normal 11px Verdana,sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
}

.plupload .plupload_container input {width: 98%;}
.plupload .plupload_filelist_footer {border-width: 1px 0 0 0}
.plupload .plupload_filelist_header {border-width: 0 0 1px 0}
div.plupload .plupload_file {border-width: 0 0 1px 0}
div.plupload div.plupload_header {border-width: 0 0 1px 0; position: relative;}

.plupload_file .ui-icon {
    cursor:pointer; 
}

.plupload_header_content {
    background-image: url('../img/plupload.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 8px center;
    min-height: 56px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    position:relative;
}
.plupload_header_content_bw {background-image: url('../img/plupload-bw.png');}
.plupload_header_title {
    font: normal 18px sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 0 3px;
}
.plupload_header_text {font: normal 12px sans-serif;}

.plupload_filelist,
.plupload_filelist_content {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}

.plupload_cell {padding: 8px 6px;}

.plupload_file {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}

.plupload .ui-sortable-helper,
.plupload .ui-sortable .plupload_file {
    cursor:move;    
}

.plupload_scroll {
    max-height: 180px;
    min-height: 168px;
    _height: 168px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.plupload_file_size, .plupload_file_status {text-align: right;}
.plupload_file_size, .plupload_file_status {width: 52px;}
.plupload_file_action {width: 16px;}
.plupload_file_name {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.plupload_file_rename {
    width:95%;  
}

.plupload_progress {width: 60px;}
.plupload_progress_container {padding: 1px;}


/* Floats */

.plupload_right {float: right;}
.plupload_left {float: left;}
.plupload_clear,.plupload_clearer {clear: both;}
.plupload_clearer, .plupload_progress_bar {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
.plupload_clearer {height: 0;}

/* Misc */
.plupload_hidden {display: none;}
.plupload_droptext {
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 165px;
}

.plupload_buttons, .plupload_upload_status {float: left}

.plupload_message {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;  
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.plupload_message p {
    padding:0.7em;
    margin:0;
}

.plupload_message strong {
    font-weight: bold;  
}

plupload_message i {
    font-style: italic; 
}

.plupload_message p span.ui-icon {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.3em;    
}

.plupload_header_content .ui-state-error,
.plupload_header_content .ui-state-highlight {
    border:none;    
}

.plupload_message_close {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:5px;
    cursor:pointer; 
}

.plupload .ui-sortable-placeholder {
    height:35px;
}
```

Comment: add a </br> after every img tag

Comment: If I add that I got the horizontal alignment anyways I rectified it thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want is `float: left;` on your images.

Functioning example: http://jsfiddle.net/NeMDZ/2/ (Try moving the middle divider. Flexible layout is optional.)

The basic CSS:

```
div.imgContain {
    overflow:hidden; /* Only necessary if you need to style the containing box.
    Forces box to expand to content's height. */
}
div.imgContain img {
    float:left;
}
```

All the other CSS is optional. Style at will.

Comment: See the result what I. getting with your code.And in the jsfiddle example what you showed is working fine

Comment: @user944919 Can we see the CSS being applied to your images?

Comment: No,I did not mention any CSS and I need it.

Comment: @user944919 Without being able to see a live page, it's hard to diagnose the problem. It looks like it may be caused by some other CSS you already had.

Comment: Sorry Nathan actually I am not using any of the css file just the plupload uploader.And I have updated my code with that css if you need you can check that.

Comment: @user944919 Is the rendered HTML (not your jQuery) like the rendered HTML code in my fiddle? ( `<div><a><img /></a><a><img /></a><a><img /></a></div>` )

Comment: Thanks nathan your code worked perfectly sorry as in the above markup I have given non-breaking space and now I removed and worked well.

Comment: And one more thing how do I give a space bettween each image.

Comment: @user944919 Try playing with `margin` or `padding` on the images; for instance, `padding:5px;` or `padding:0 5px;` for only horizontal padding.

Comment: Thanks once again you helped me a lot.Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
display: inline-box;
}
```

The images will set in the same line as long they fit there. Be very careful with `padding` and `margin` values.

Answer (score 1):

Images are block-level elements by default, so you will need `float: left` on your images (or whatever element your image is contained in) if you want them to be side-by-side. If you want to start a new line, create a spacer element like:

```
.spacer {
    clear: both;
}
```

and then add `<div class="spacer"></div>` where you want to break a line of images and start a new one. You may need other attributes on your spacer to work in old browsers.

Comment: Tempted to down-vote for suggesting unsemantic markup, but refrained.

Comment: With this I'm able them to place horizontally.